# Vue: get list of components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have simple component structure for my single page website:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header />
    <section-about />
    <section-warranty />
    <section-advantages />
    <section-service />
    <section-review />
    <footer />
    <menu />
  </div>
</template>
```

And now I want to list all web page blocks (article sections) in menu component.

[image]

Ofcourse I can write this list manually but I wonder if possible to parse all my components for some key and as a result make list from them. So that my menu list will be based on components and will be updated automatically if I add some new article component or remove one.

I.e. `Warranty.vue` component:

```
<template>
   <section class="article warranty">
      ...blah blah blah...
   </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         article-key: 'warranty', // <-- key for parsing
         article-title: 'Warranty'
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Then other article components in the same way...

And now my `Menu.vue` component:

```
<template>
   <ul class="menu">
      <li v-for="(article, index) in articles" :key="index">
         <a href="#">{{ article.title }}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         articles: []
      }
   },
   methods: {
      parseComponents() {
         this.articles = ... <-- for each Vue component if has article-key data then return
      }
   },
   created() {
      parseComponents()
   }
}
</script>
```

Or should I just move all articles in separate folder? Is this possible to make vith Vue?

Comment: If all your possible components will be a child of a given parent component - you could enumerate them in the parent with `this.$children`. Otherwise you will have to traverse the whole component hierarchy starting from the root Vue instance - and you will be able to enumerate only live components but not those which are hidden behind a `v-if` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution.

```
<template>
   <div class="menu">
      <ul class="menu-list">
         <li v-for="(article, index) in articles" :key="index">
            <a href="#" @click.prevent="article.el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end'})">{{ article.title }}</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         articles: []
      }
   },
   mounted() {
      this.articles= this.$parent.$children.map(article=> {
         return article.$data.articleKey == 'article' ? {
            title: article.$data.articleTitle,
            offsetTop: article.$el.offsetTop,
            el: article.$el
         } : false;
      })
   }
}
</script>
```

Also it will be interesting to find approach for parsing components by its name from whole folder with regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all this values in `this.articles` you could do:

```
this.articles.map(el => {
    if(el.article-key) {
        return <MyComponent/>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with defining list of your components:

```
computed: {
  components() {
    return ['about', 'warranty', 'advantages', 'service', 'review']
  }
}
```

render them in this way (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is)

```
<component v-for="component in components" :key="component" :is="component" />
```

With this approach you should write your components list only once

To use them on Menu component - make prop (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) to pass them